# Webservice to call an Oracle stored procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, oracle, web-services

I have a requirement to build a webservice which will call an Oracle stored procedure, the stored procedure will return a ref cursor, and the webservice has to present the data in xml format.

I have the Oracle command code set up to call the stored procedure, and I have classes set up detailing the structure of the objects I want to present, ([DataContract] with [DataMembers]).

Can anyone point me to a good example of what Im missing to hook this all up?  Im not looking for anyone to do my work for me, just not sure of where to go from here as Ive not worked with Oracle Stored procedures before

Here's what I have at the moment

```
[WebMethod]
    public DataSet PaymentAccDetails(Int32 strParRefNo)
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(ConnectionHelper.HousingDBConnectionString);
        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        cmd.CommandText = "Get_payment_acc_details_crm"; ;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("pParRefno", OracleType.Number)).Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("oCursor", OracleType.Cursor)).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd);
        conn.Open();
        OracleDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        da.Fill(ds);
        conn.Close();
        return (ds);

    }
```

And I want to return the data in this format.  I can see my web methods when I view it in the browser, not sure of how to change this so that the data gets returned.

```
[DataContract]
public class PaymentAccDetails
{
    [DataMember(Order = 1)]
    public string PaymentRef
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    [DataMember(Order = 2)]
    public DateTime StartDate
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    [DataMember(Order = 3)]
    public DateTime EndDate
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    [DataMember(Order = 4)]
    public string AccountType
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    [DataMember(Order = 5)]
    public string PaymentMethod
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    [DataMember(Order = 6)]
    public DateTime LastPaidDate
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    [DataMember(Order = 7)]
    public string Balance
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

}
```

thanks

Comment: Please post what you already have, so we can fill in. You said you have the procedure call and the data transfer objects... then you are done. What is it, you are missing?

Comment: Typically I'd think you'd use the ref cursor to fill a DataTable or a DataSet and return that from the web service.  That should be fairly straightforward to do.  There are even [MSDN docs on it here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w0ya43t5(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I have pretty much what is in the MSDN example, other than viewing the data via a gridview I just want it presented as xml when the service is invoked, is that fairly easy also?